# Otherwise as a Conjunction; does the second clause become a dependant clause when we use otherwise as a conditional?

Tags: british-english, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

If we have two independent clauses, which can stand on their own as complete sentences. When we join the two with a conditional such as "otherwise". The second clause, now headed by "Otherwise," must surely become dependent on the first clause as without it there is not a conditional. If my case is proven, then how does this affect the punctuation of the new sentence?

> "You have to start studying otherwise you will fail your exams."

Comment: This question may help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331802/what-parts-of-speech-are-or-else-and-otherwise-and-why-is-otherwise-more and see also https://www.une.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/10024/WC_Punctuating-with-commas.pdf Both recommend a semicolon or full stop before "otherwise".

Comment: Your sentence is not that different from: You have to start studying, **or** you will fail your exams. There, a comma is enough.

Comment: The sentence should have a comma before _otherwise_. And the following clause is dependent to start with, because _otherwise_ is a subordinator, not an independent one like _and_, so you didn't start with two independent clauses after all.

Comment: @John Lawler  I find your answer rather interesting. In this case, I am using otherwise the same as I would **or**, therefore why do you class it as a subordinator,. C.E.D. Quote; We often use or and otherwise with conditional meanings. The second clause **You will fail your exams** does not meet the criteria of  "a subordinate clause does not complete a thought on its own, which means it can’t act as a sentence on its own". *Please note I am not saying you are incorrect I am saying I don't understand why!*

Comment: @Yosef Baskin My foremost concern is with the change of independent to dependent clause, however with regard to punctuation; That is exactly the reason behind my question. Although my thoughts are that it should be "You have to start studying, otherwise, you will fail your exams". The extra comma being for two syllables as opposed to one,